# addSqlCommenterCommentToQueries open telemetry with auto-instrumentations-node

Tags: node.js, postgresql, open-telemetry

I'm trying to add an sql comment on my queries using opentelemetry node auto instrumentations and addSqlCommenterCommentToQueries flag within @opentelemetry/instrumentation-pg.
All the instrumentations seems to be working but the sql comment is not there.

This is how I configured it at the instrumentation.js file:

```
const { NodeSDK } = require('@opentelemetry/sdk-node');
const { ConsoleSpanExporter } = require('@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node');
const {
    OTLPTraceExporter,
  } = require('@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-proto');
const {
  getNodeAutoInstrumentations
} = require('@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node');
const {
  PeriodicExportingMetricReader,
  ConsoleMetricExporter,
} = require('@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics');

const sdk = new NodeSDK({
    serviceName: "node-express-otel",
  traceExporter: new OTLPTraceExporter({
    url: 'http://localhost:4318/v1/traces',
    headers: {},
  }),
  instrumentations: [
    getNodeAutoInstrumentations({
    "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-pg": {
        addSqlCommenterCommentToQueries: true,
      },
  })],
});



sdk.start();
```

I was expecting the queries to have an sql comment with the trace data.